# Repurposed amplifier sanity check + ground connections

Tags: circuit-design, power-amplifier, hacking

I want to use the audio amplifer from a scrapped TV control board ([Sony 1-876-561-13](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/792956/Sony-Kdl-40z4100.html?page=60#)).

The amp section is built around a TI [TPA3100D2](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3100d2.pdf?ts=1640275470471&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTPA3100D2) chip. The original input was a PWM audio signal from some other chip, which was passed through a filter section to convert it to an analog signal before shooting it into the amp.

I've physically cut the amp section off of the original PCB. Because of the layout, I have to run my new analog inputs (I'm not using PWM) sort of in the middle of the old PWM filter. My plan right now is:

[image]

Where:

- The main circuit there (from the service manual) is the old PWM filter.
- The red hatched area physically no longer exists. The schematic accurately represents the remaining broken traces.
- The green parts of the schematic are what I'm planning to add. The green dots can't be placed elsewhere; they correspond to the only accessible physical tap points for signal input.
- The thicker schematic lines are grounds. However, the ground line for the PWM filter (PWM_GND) was not directly connected (on the PCB anyways) to the rest of the audio grounds; it was some other ground from the PWM source with lots of noise suppression and decoupling around it.

So, I have two questions here. Both of them are centered around making sure the remaining portions of the old PWM filter don't interfere with my new analog inputs:

1. I've marked the remaining (now unconnected) PWM_GND points with `???`. Should I leave them unconnected or should I tie them to the amp grounds (on the right)? Or should I just remove the four 470p caps entirely (feasible but not ideal)?
2. R- and L- will ultimately be connected to my signal source's ground (which will almost certainly be tied to the amp ground at some point). Will running them through that 1k resistor block (RB2015) mess up the signal? I feel like it should but otoh maybe the coupling capacitors + internal amp circuitry do some magic that makes it not matter? In an ideal world I'd just tap into the other side of those resistors, but there's no access there. I could theoretically remove / jump them but it's a task I'd like to avoid if possible.

So yeah, those are my questions: What to do with the remaining old filter capacitors and whether or not I need to find a way around RB2015.

Comment: The D3 chip isn't covered in the data sheet

Comment: @Andyaka D2; typo sorry. Thanks for noticing. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your diagram a tiny bit wrong. For left channel you should keep both neg and pos feeding their equivalent circuit nodes: -

[image]

And join up the "???" nodes to GND also.

> *The green dots can't be placed elsewhere; they correspond to the only
> accessible physical tap points for signal input.*

Well, it's not ideal but it's worth a shot.

> *R- and L- will ultimately be connected to my signal source's ground
> (which will almost certainly be tied to the amp ground at some point).
> Will running them through that 1k resistor block (RB2015) mess up the
> signal?*

No but, if you wanted to avoid those resistors and feed directly after them then you would probably remove the 4 x 470 pF capacitors.

Given what you said about the green dots being the only accessible points, I would make the input+ lines tied to ground (single-ended input) and feed the actual inputs to each input- line.

Comment: So on a second look, I actually can run all 4 signal lines through the 1k resistors like your diagram. If I do that and also ground those capacitors then it puts a low pass filter on every input but, if my math is right the cutoff is a few hundred kHz with no appreciable phase distortion so it won't matter for audio. So that's the way to go then, yeah?

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me @JasonC

Comment: [It worked!](https://youtu.be/GBLg6eOiN_M). Although, ironically, after all this discussion, I ended up skipping that resistor block and removing the capacitors there -- not by choice, but let's just say a freak accident involving a hot glue gun, a cat, and a dremel sort of... made the choice for me (still not entirely sure what happened). Thanks a lot!!! Nice little amp, too; no power on/off spikes, a bit sensitive to input line noise (need to figure that out) but the circuit itself is dead silent, thermal and fault protection; draws like 40mA tops, and ran fine down to an 8V supply. Sweet.

Comment: Sounds good; maybe use the inputs differentially all the way to the source of the signal to reduce rogue noise. That's why it has differential inputs (if you can stop the cat ruining 2 more connections. Use shielded twisted pair if you can.

Comment: Hey thanks again! Twisted pair is a good idea. There's something else going on there though. I'm going to ask a new question about it after I eat dinner and read up on amp designs, if my Google searches don't pan out.